# Is there a way to load an applet in chrome extension?

Tags: java, applet, google-chrome-extension

I have written a class for my application and want to use it in making chrome extension.I tried loading applet in popup.but it seems that chrome has blocked applets. The functionality i want to embed is when user visits a page he sees a button on omnibox..when user clicks the button i want to send some page elements to my applet which processes it and saves it as a file in the filesytem. for this i want to dynamically add the applet to dom..or atleast if i can load the applet its fine!!

Comment: Is this applet hosted remotely or you want to load it from your extension folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known limitation between Java Applets and Google Chrome, for more information please refer to the following issue: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30258